# Problema Sign in Google al instalar apk generada

Tags: java, android, android-studio, login

Buenas tengo una aplicación desarrollada en android studio, el inicio con google me funciona perfectamente cuando la instalo con el ordenador pero al instalar el apk generado con android studio no me inicia sesión es decir cuando le doy al botón y elijo la cuenta de google no hace nada, os dejos datos por aquí ya que tengo la versión compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0' y compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0', ademas tengo generado el sha1 release y sigue igual sin poderse iniciar sesión, no se que mas hacer ya que no consigo arreglar el problema.
Muchas Gracias.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.juansevillano.testingproductos"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


 productFlavors {
    }
}

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'jsr305'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Hey Juan bienvenido!... "me funciona perfectamente cuando la instalo con el ordenador pero al instalar el apk generado con android studio" a que refieres, para mi es lo mismo. Revisa [ask].

Comment: Se supone que es lo mismo pero como he comprobado no es lo mismo. El problemas surge cuando intento iniciar con la cuenta de google en mi aplicación ya que me dice que no se puede iniciar sesión, la instalación del apk la realiza de forma correcta. La misma aplicación instalada desde el ordenador mediante android studio funciona perfectamente. He leido por algunos foros que es cosa de que no genero el sha release. Muchas Gracias

Comment: Ok instalada desde android studio funciona correctamente, pero como generas y como instalas el .apk que no funciona? @JuanSevillano

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenia un problema parecido y era las librerías de support, deben ser todas de la misma versión, por ejemplo en tu gradle tienes

```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Las dos deberían ser 25.3.0 o 25.3.1-. Espero que te funcione también!

Comment: Ya lo he resuelto el problema es debido a esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39697905/generate-sha1-fingerprint-in-android-studio-2-2 he generado el release y creado la configuración necesario y despues he realizado el build APK y resuelto muchas gracias a todos compañeros.